# <DebugType>none</DebugType> leads to Xamarin App not compiling in Debug

Tags: xamarin, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022 with a Xamarin project that works and builds going through the "release steps" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows leads to a project that will only build in release mode. In debug mode the below errors occur. AFTER HOURS of tracking it down I am able to fix the build by removing the following line from the project file in the  section.

```
<DebugType>none</DebugType>
```

This is the error when in Debug mode with the above line in the project file. Build works just fine in release. Main error appears to be  The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: TechClient.Mobile, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018: The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'Mono.Cecil, Version=0.10.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e'.
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018: 
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018: Server stack trace: 
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018: 
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018: Exception rethrown at [0]: 
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Users\marti\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2401\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets(119,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>Done building project "TechClient.Mobile.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Why was the "debug" line added and is it needed? What should I do about it to keep the security that the preparing a Xamarin for release document talks about?

So far I have just been removing the none line when I want to debug and adding it back in for releases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: none is not a valid DebugType: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/code-generation#debugtype

Comment: If that `<DebugType>` line **IS NOT inside** a block similar to `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|...'">`, then **delete** it. If it **IS inside** a Debug Configuration, then **change** it to `<DebugType>portable</DebugType>` or `<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>`. For your purposes, probably doesn't matter which of those you use. But looking at a recently created xamarin forms project, I see `portable` used.